# Show/hide on a prefilled form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a question. If answered yes, a set of checkboxes appears; if answered no nothing happens.

```
<tr>
  <td>Question?</td>
  <td>
    <label><input name="selector" type="radio" value="yes" />Yes</label>
    <label><input name="selector" type="radio" value="no" />No</label>
    <br />
    <div id="subset">
      <label class="disabled"><input name="select1" type="checkbox" value="select1" />option1</label><br />
      <label class="disabled"><input name="select2" type="checkbox" value="select2" />option2</label><br />
      <label class="disabled"><input name="select3" type="checkbox" value="select3" />option3</label><br />
      <label class="disabled"><input name="select4" type="checkbox" value="select4" />option4</label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=selector]').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).val();

      if (selector == 'no') {
        $('#subset label').addClass('disabled');
        $('#subset input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#subset input').attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $('#subset label').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#subset input').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code works fine but the form can be pre-filled. If so it has to work the same way: if yes is selected the sset should be visible.

I know I can easily do this with jQuery again in a separate block of code (see below) but I was hoping I could do this by only altering the existing code a little.

```
var selector = $('input[name=selector]:checked').val();
if (selector == 'no') {
  $('#subset label').addClass('disabled');
  $('#subset input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#subset input').attr('checked', false);
} else {
  $('#subset label').removeClass('disabled');
  $('#subset input').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

The pre-fill is done with smarty and looks something like the code below, which I put in all the radio and checkbox tags.

```
{{if $array.ELEMENT.answer=='VALUE'}} checked{{/if}}
```

So the question is, how can I get the extra functionality without adding a lot of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just **trigger** the click event  .. in the **DOM** ready event..

```
$(function(){
   $('input[name=selector]').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).val();

      if (selector == 'no') {
        $('#subset label').addClass('disabled');
        $('#subset input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#subset input').attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $('#subset label').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#subset input').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
    $('input[name=selector]:checked')​.click();​
   // Will trigger the click event on page load
});
```

So based on the pre filled form this event will be triggered for the checked item.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/spbph/)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you refactor your click handler into a function and invoke that code on click and on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's `toggleClass`.  It adds/removes the class with each alternate call.
See http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just isolate your function in a separate block:

```
function processForm(){
  var selector = $('input[name=selector]:checked').val();

  if (selector == 'no') {
    $('#subset label').addClass('disabled');
    $('#subset input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#subset input').attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('#subset label').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#subset input').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

You can then call it directly or within your click.